# Qt: How to call a set to a toString, return in get function and testing a bool

Tags: qt

I need to write a program that asks the user for his/her address with the QInputDialog (the input is just separated by a comma) and then displays the address in this format with a QMessageBox:

```
32 Menlyn Street
Lynnwood Glen
Pretoria
0002
```

The setLines() member function should split an address string into lines, indicated by the separator string, and store them in the lines data member.

The getPostalCode() member function should return the last line of the address.

The toString() member function should return a single string comprising a combination of all the lines of the address, with the separator string inserted between them.

The static isPostalCode() function should test whether a specified string
represents a postal code, in particular a series of 4 digits.

This is what I have for the .h file:

```
#ifndef ADDRESS_H
#define ADDRESS_H

#include <QString>
#include <QStringList>

class Address{
public:
    Address();
    void setLines(QString ad, QString sep);
    QString getPostalCode() const;
    QString toString(QString sep) const;
    static bool isPostalCode(QString pc);
private:
    QStringList lines;
};

#endif // ADDRESS_H
```

This is my .cpp file which I need help with. I know what I must do but don't know how and where to start:

```
#include "address.h"
#include "QInputDialog"
#include "QMessageBox"

Address::Address(){}

void Address::setLines(QString ad, QString sep){

}

QString Address::getPostalCode() const{
    //return
}

QString Address::toString(QString sep) const{
    //return sep = QString("The address you
    entered:\n");//.arg(setLines(address, separate));
}

bool Address::isPostalCode(QString pc){
    //if
}
```

And this my main file:

```
#include "address.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QInputDialog>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QString>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    bool ok;

    while(true)
    {
        QString userInput = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Address Input","Please enter your address separated by a comma\n(For example: 32 Menlyn Street,Lynwood Glen,Pretoria,0002)", QLineEdit::Normal, QString(), &ok);
        if (ok && !userInput.isEmpty())
        {
            Address ad;

            QMessageBox::information(0, "User Address", ad.toStr ing(userInput),QMessageBox::Ok);
        }
        else break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please no nasty comments, I really need help to know how to do this Qt.

Comment: in `setLines()` use `lines = ad.split(sep);`

Comment: in `getPostalCode()` use `return lines.last();`

Comment: for `toString()` use `lines.join(sep)`